# How to analyze Bluetooth Low Energy traffic in Wireshark

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am trying to analyze the traffic captured for a blue Bluetooth Low Energy device in wireshark.

I have figured out that data is transferred using the ATT protocol, but I do not see anywhere that explains how the ATT protocol works and hence how to interpret the data that I see. Anyone understands ATT and how it is used to transmit data and hence how I can read the data transmitted via Wireshark?

Comment: Did you try the [bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com) website? GATT specs can be found there.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck?  Have you captured data?  Have you loaded the capture into wireshark?  Have you activated suitable decoders?  What is the source and nature of the data, and what do you hope to learn?  This can indeed be a powerful tool, but it's unclear what your *exact* difficulty is.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way is to use [nRF Sniffer](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-Tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE) by Nordic Semi to view the BLE packets in Wireshark